# Update application in google play

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

I have a question related with updating android app in google play. I have so far application (.apk) which was generated by paid tools which not give me .keystore file. Now i have to generate app by my own and I choose react native expo. Is it possible to migrate from .apk to .aab with new keystore if i lose my previous one and still offer update app for users who has already app on their mobile phones?

I try to generate new .keystore locally and update app in google play but Im afraid about compatibility with updating app if users has already it. I dont have old .keystore file anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to update your existing app without app's .keystore file. If you are create a new key you must create a new app with a different package name on play console.

Comment: Are you sure because i found sth like that: "Google uses the upload certificate to verify your identity, and signs your APK(s) with your app signing key for distribution as shown in figure 1. By using a separate upload key you can request an upload key reset if your key is ever lost or compromised.

By comparison, for apps created before August 2021 that have not opted in to Play App Signing, if you lose your app’s signing key, you lose the ability to update your app."

So if I understand there are App signing key and Upload key and upload key  and only upload key can be changed?

Comment: As far as I know there is no clear solution for this but you can contact the support team as shown this  [doc](https://professnow.com/blog/how-to-upload-new-keystore-or-app-signing-key-in-google-play-console-after-lost-or-forget-keystore/).